# sorting to DASC does not work in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

```
$model = new TableName('search');

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
        $model = $model->findAll($criteria);

        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if (isset($_GET['TableName']))
            $model->attributes = $_GET['TableName'];

        $this->render('TableNameView', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
```

after use this code gets a white screen, no any action, and it should sort the why this is happening and how can I fix this way?

Comment: specifically I used "TableName" to change the original name :)

Comment: I suppose `$model = $model->findAll($criteria);` rewirtes the type of `$model` var

Comment: only when you will use the 'find' instead of 'findAll' then works but displays only one result so it's not

Comment: I checked and "findall" does not work even when we do not give any value when I open gets just a white screen and when proof, "source code" is also nothing

Comment: Please show the source code of your `search` function inside the model TableName

Answer (score 0):

You override the original value of `$model` variable.

```
$model = $model->findAll($criteria);
```

After that `$model` is not an instance of `TableName` anymore! `findAll` [returns](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) a **list** of `TableName`'s. So, you must iterate throught this list to get a single instance of `TableName`.

```
$models = $model->findAll($criteria);
foreach( $models as $model ) {
    // do something with $model
}
```

Or, if you just need to get the last record, you can use `find`:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->order = 'id DESC';
$model = $model->find($criteria);
```

Comment: does not work :(   |
findAll = blank screen   |

find = one record

Comment: Could you be more specific, what exactly doesn't work? findAll will not work without the foreach loop. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: with this code I have only one record displayed, it correctly but only one: /
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
        $model = $model->find($criteria);


        http://oi60.tinypic.com/1z1bs6x.jpg

Comment: and will use this code when such effect as in the picture
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
        $models = $model->findAll($criteria);
        foreach( $models as $model ) {
            print_r($model);
            echo $model;
        }

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2zpm4qc.jpg